# React mount point in wagtail admin

Tags: wagtail

I'm trying to understand how wagtail's admin works. I'm familiar with both Django and React but separately.

I understand that React's code is developed under `/client`. And that the transformed version lives in `/wagtail/admin/static_src/wagtailadmin/js/`

As a starting point I looked at [admin_base.html](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/admin_base.html), and feel that the two relevant entries are:

`<script src="{% static 'wagtailadmin/js/core.js' %}"></script>`

`<script src="{% static 'wagtailadmin/js/wagtailadmin.js' %}"></script>`.

I'm not sure what files they correspond to under `/client`. And where they mount on Django templates.

Comment: Did you solve that?